# Proving convexity for higher dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose I have a function $f(a,b,c)=\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}$ for $a,b,c>0$. How can I show that it is convex? By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) of convexity, I have to show that $$f(tX+(1-t)Y)\leq tf(X)+(1-t)f(Y)$$ for all $X,Y\in R_{>0}^3$ and $t\in[0,1]$. But this seems very complicated. Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is the sum of three functions.  You might be able to show that each of them is convex, in which case the sum is also convex. Notice that the first function $(a,b,c)\mapsto {1\over a+b}$ is the composition of the linear function $(a,b,c)\mapsto a+b$ with the convex funtion $0<t\mapsto 1/t$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If a function $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$, then $f$ is convex iff $\nabla^2f$ is a positive definite matrix over its domain.